# Powershell GUI using PDF Sharp for password protection

Tags: powershell, user-interface, powershell-4.0, pdfsharp

I am trying to create a simple form that will do the following

1. Browse for an already created pdf
2. Have a text boxt that should accept text/numbers/special characters that will be served to create the password
3. Get prompt where to save the pdf file that has been password protected and add at the end _protected or something so I can save it in the same place without overwriting.
   I did create a part of the code, but I have issues such as - How can I create a button that will help me with the destination location?
   I can't seem to make the text box act as a password input also it seems that when I click the browse button it doesn't load properly the file?
   Running the code itself by just using the set-pdf password with the params is working great ( not my code there) but I seem to have issues creating a form for this.
   Could anyone offer some hints on the top questions?

```
#############################################Functions##################################################################
function Set-PdfPassword {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Protects the PDF with a password
.PARAMETER SourceFile
Path to the SourceFile
.PARAMETER DestinationFile
Password for the file
.PARAMETER Password
Full path of the password protected PDF
.PARAMETER PdfSharpPath
Full path to the required PdfSharp library
.PARAMETER Force
Tries to force destination file and directory creation and deletion of source files, even when they are read-only
.PARAMETER
RemoveSourceFiles
Deletes the source files after PDF is merged
.EXAMPLE
Set-PdfPassword -SourceFile "C:\TEMP\test.pdf" -DestinationFile "C:\TEMP\protected_test.pdf" -Password "SECRET" -PdfSharpPath 'C:\ProgramData\coolOrange\powerJobs\Modules\PdfSharp-gdi.dll' -Force -RemoveSourceFiles
#>
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[System.IO.FileInfo]$SourceFile=
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[System.IO.FileInfo]$DestinationFile,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]$Password=
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
$PdfSharpPath,
[switch]$Force,
[switch]$RemoveSourceFiles
)

    Write-Host ">> $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name) >>"

    if((Test-Path $PdfSharpPath) -eq $false) {
        throw "Could not find pdfsharp assembly at $($PdfSharpPath)"
    }
    Add-Type -LiteralPath $PdfSharpPath

    if((Test-Path $DestinationFile.FullName) -and $DestinationFile.IsReadOnly -and -not $Force) {
        throw "Destination file '$($DestinationFile.FullName)' is read only"
    }

    $document = [PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader]::Open($SourceFile.FullName)
    $securitySettings = $document.SecuritySettings;
    
    # Set Password
    $securitySettings.UserPassword = $Password

    # Restrict some permissions
    $securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitFormsFill = $true;
    $securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = $true;
    $securitySettings.PermitPrint = $false;

    Write-Host "Saving PDF"
    if((Test-Path $DestinationFile.FullName) -and $Force) { 
        Remove-Item $DestinationFile.FullName -Force 
    }
    $document.Save($DestinationFile.FullName)
}

function Select-FolderDialog {
  param([String]$Description="Select Folder", 
        [String]$RootFolder="Desktop")   

  $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
  $objForm.Rootfolder = $RootFolder
  $objForm.Description = $Description
  $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()
  if ($Show -eq "OK")
  {
     return $objForm.SelectedPath
  }
}
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
    Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)| *.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
} 

###################### CREATING PS GUI TOOL #############################

    #### Form settings #################################################################
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle #modifies the window border
    $Form.Text = "Powershell Password Generator"    
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1010,400)  
    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen
    $Form.BackgroundImageLayout = "Zoom"
    $Form.MinimizeBox = $False
    $Form.MaximizeBox = $False
    $Form.WindowState = "Normal"
    $Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
    $Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
    $Form.Icon = $Icon
     #### Title - Powershell GUI Tool ###################################################
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",18,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $Label.Font = $LabelFont
    $Label.Text = "PasswordProtector v.1"
    $Label.AutoSize = $True
    $Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(415,40) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($Label)
        #### Input window with "Password For PDF" label ##########################################
    $InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) 
    $InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($InputBox)
    $Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label2.Text = "Enter Password for PDF"
    $Label2.AutoSize = $True
    $Label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,30) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($Label2)
     #### Group boxes for buttons ########################################################
    $groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    $groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,95) 
    $groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,270)
    $groupBox.text = "Options" 
    
    $Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)
        #### Browse #################################################################
    $Browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Browse.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,30)
    $Browse.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,60)
    $Browse.Text = "Browse For PDF"
    $Browse.Add_Click({Get-FileName})
    $Browse.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Browse)
            #### Output #################################################################
    $Password = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Password.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,110)
    $Password.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,60)
    $Password.Text = "Set PDF Password"
    $Password.Add_Click({Set-PdfPassword})
    $Password.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Password)
    ###################### END BUTTONS ######################################################

    #### Output Box Field ###############################################################
    $outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    $outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,100) 
    $outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(780,265)
    $outputBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 8 ,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
    $outputBox.MultiLine = $True
    $outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $outputBox.Text = " `
          Welcome to PDF Password Generator."
    $Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)

    ##############################################

    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have PDF Sharp Library, so I can not test completely, but I made some changes to retrieve the selected source file, calculate the destination file with "_Protected" suffix  and add these informations in the output Rich Text Box

```
#Functions
function Set-PdfPassword {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Protects the PDF with a password
.PARAMETER SourceFile
Path to the SourceFile
.PARAMETER DestinationFile
Password for the file
.PARAMETER Password
Full path of the password protected PDF
.PARAMETER PdfSharpPath
Full path to the required PdfSharp library
.PARAMETER Force
Tries to force destination file and directory creation and deletion of source files, even when they are read-only
.PARAMETER
RemoveSourceFiles
Deletes the source files after PDF is merged
.EXAMPLE
Set-PdfPassword -SourceFile "C:\TEMP\test.pdf" -DestinationFile "C:\TEMP\protected_test.pdf" -Password "SECRET" -PdfSharpPath 'C:\ProgramData\coolOrange\powerJobs\Modules\PdfSharp-gdi.dll' -Force -RemoveSourceFiles
#>
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[System.IO.FileInfo]$SourceFile=
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[System.IO.FileInfo]$DestinationFile,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]$Password=
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
$PdfSharpPath,
[switch]$Force,
[switch]$RemoveSourceFiles
)

    Write-Host ">> $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name) >>"

    if((Test-Path $PdfSharpPath) -eq $false) {
        throw "Could not find pdfsharp assembly at $($PdfSharpPath)"
    }
    Add-Type -LiteralPath $PdfSharpPath

    if((Test-Path $DestinationFile.FullName) -and $DestinationFile.IsReadOnly -and -not $Force) {
        throw "Destination file '$($DestinationFile.FullName)' is read only"
    }

    $document = [PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader]::Open($SourceFile.FullName)
    $securitySettings = $document.SecuritySettings;

    # Set Password
    $securitySettings.UserPassword = $Password
    
    # Restrict some permissions
    $securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitFormsFill = $true;
    $securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = $false;
    $securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = $true;
    $securitySettings.PermitPrint = $false;

    Write-Host "Saving PDF"
    if((Test-Path $DestinationFile.FullName) -and $Force) { 
        Remove-Item $DestinationFile.FullName -Force 
    }
    $document.Save($DestinationFile.FullName)
}

function Select-FolderDialog {
  param([String]$Description="Select Folder", 
        [String]$RootFolder="Desktop")   

  $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
  $objForm.Rootfolder = $RootFolder
  $objForm.Description = $Description
  $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()
  if ($Show -eq "OK")
  {
     return $objForm.SelectedPath


  }
}
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
    Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)| *.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename

    $Script:SourceFile = $OpenFileDialog.filename

    $Filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName)
    $FileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName)
    $FileFolder = split-path $SourceFile -Parent
    $Script:DestinationFile = $FileFolder + "\" + $Filename + "_Protected" + $FileExtension

    $outputBox.Appendtext("$([char]10)")
    $outputBox.Appendtext("$([char]10)")
    $outputBox.Appendtext("Selected File :")
    $outputBox.Appendtext("$([char]10)")
    $outputBox.Appendtext($SourceFile)
    $outputBox.Appendtext("$([char]10)")
    $outputBox.Appendtext("will be saved to :")
    $outputBox.Appendtext("$([char]10)")
    $outputBox.Appendtext($DestinationFile)
} 

    # CREATING PS GUI TOOL

    #Form settings
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle #modifies the window border
    $Form.Text = "Powershell Password Generator"    
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1010,400)  
    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen
    $Form.BackgroundImageLayout = "Zoom"
    $Form.MinimizeBox = $False
    $Form.MaximizeBox = $False
    $Form.WindowState = "Normal"
    $Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
    $Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
    $Form.Icon = $Icon
    #Title - Powershell GUI Tool
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",18,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $Label.Font = $LabelFont
    $Label.Text = "PasswordProtector v.1"
    $Label.AutoSize = $True
    $Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(415,40) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($Label)
    #Input window with "Password For PDF" label
    $InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) 
    $InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($InputBox)

    $Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label2.Text = "Enter Password for PDF"
    $Label2.AutoSize = $True
    $Label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,30) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($Label2)
    #Group boxes for buttons
    $groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    $groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,95) 
    $groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,270)
    $groupBox.text = "Options" 

    $Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)
    #Browse
    $Browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Browse.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,30)
    $Browse.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,60)
    $Browse.Text = "Browse For PDF"
    $Browse.Add_Click({Get-FileName})
    $Browse.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Browse)
    #Output
    $PasswordButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $PasswordButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,110)
    $PasswordButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,60)
    $PasswordButton.Text = "Set PDF Password"
    $PasswordButton.Add_Click({Set-PdfPassword -sourcefile $SourceFile -DestinationFile $DestinationFile -Password ($InputBox.Text)})
    $PasswordButton.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($PasswordButton)
    #END BUTTONS

    #Output Box Field
    $outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    $outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,100) 
    $outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(780,265)
    $outputBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 8 ,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
    $outputBox.MultiLine = $True
    $outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $outputBox.Text = " `
          Welcome to PDF Password Generator."
    $Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)

    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: `Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:103 char:30
+     $FileFolder = split-path $SourceFile -Parent
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCommand
 `

Comment: `Set-PdfPassword : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DestinationFile'.
At line:173 char:72
+ ... ick({Set-PdfPassword -sourcefile $SourceFile -DestinationFile $Destin ...
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-PdfPassword], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-PdfPassword `

Comment: Most likely the above two errors are due to the pdf sharp library that I do not have on this laptop as I am at work, will work through when I get on my personal computer, as this is a personal mini project , thanks for the edit/changes and help - will get back to this post later today.

Comment: At line 25,  please change the equal to a comma : "[System.IO.FileInfo]$SourceFile=" must be : "[System.IO.FileInfo]$SourceFile,"

Comment: running this script and adding the dll into the folder from where the script runns seems not to detect it. 
`
Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\lored\Downloads\powershell script\powershell\script.ps1:42 char:17
+     if ((Test-Path $PdfSharpPath) -eq $false)
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
 `

Comment: Ok people, nearly all of the issues, I have only two issues : after I press run the script does it job, but the script keeps running after, it should stop after success of copy, still working through this one. I currently have no idea what should I have to do to stop it. 

2nd. the PDFsharp.dll should be referenced inside the same folder as the script if I want to create an executable to run it on other computers without having to use powershell ?

Comment: you can close the form after success of copy with:  $Form.Close()

Comment: To create an executable, put the DLL in the same folder of the script, set the variable $PdfSharpPath = "$PSScriptRoot\PdfSharp.dll" and use a tool "ps1 to EXE", this one for example : http://www.systanddeploy.com/2017/11/ps1-to-exe-generator-new-version.html

Comment: thanks, but if I use the ` "$PSScriptRoot\PdfSharp.dll" ` - running the script before doing the exe file is quite with a lot of errors and the protected pdf is not getting generated. do I need to initialize the `$PSScriptRoot ` somehow ?

Comment: ok, try to use  $PdfSharpPath = ".\PdfSharp.dll" if it does not work, you can try to encode/decode your DLL : https://www.loginvsi.com/login-vsi-blog/565-embed-external-files-in-powershell-scripts

Comment: is there anyway i can use this to encrypt multiple pdf files at a time? this script is amazing, really could do where multiple files are encrypted at the same time.